# Is a UK visa needed for a British citizen's non-EU family member

Tags: visas

Is a UK visa needed for a British citizen's non-EU family member (who holds an EU Family Member Residence Card) if they wish to visit the UK together for a holiday? 
I have residence permit as a family member of eu/eea citizen in Netherlands.  I am from Turkey 
I have a daughter British citizen (my wife has UK indefinitely leave to remain residence permit thats how my daughter obtained British citizenship) she goes to school in Netherlands and we have been living here for 2 years and I am self employed person in Netherlands

Comment: Will the holiday take place before March 29?

Comment: Also: What is your wife's nationality? As far as I understand you shouldn't have gotten a "family member of a union citizen" residence card simply as the father of a school-age union citizen: parents are only considered "family members" if they are dependent on the citizen.

Comment: Yes It will be before 29th of March and my wife is turkish but she has UK ilr  as I mention above and I do have residence permit of family member of eu/eea citizen from Dutch authorities that I can confirm for 5 years